# Connecting 3d bodies into one

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, asymptote, tikz-3dplot

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62339/106013) is a nice way to make some 3d objects, but I've failed to find a way to connect two 3d objects into single one object like this one (also it would be nice to know how to add arrows with numbers):

[image: two 3d objects connected]

This is the MWE I've tried so far (just copied [the code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62339/106013) and removed some parts). I have no idea how to rotate them, also how to draw half cylinder. I don't even know if that's the right direction to go. But the main problem is connecting 3d objects, if that's possible.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}     
\usepackage{xkeyval,tkz-base}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
 \makeatletter%     

\define@cmdkey[TKZ]{ell}{color}{}
\define@cmdkey[TKZ]{ell}{shift}{}  
\presetkeys[TKZ]{ell}{color = {},shift = 0}{}

\newcommand*{\ellipseThreeD}[1][]{\tkz@ellipseThreeD[#1]}% 
\def\tkz@ellipseThreeD[#1](#2,#3)(#4,#5){%
\setkeys[TKZ]{ell}{#1}%
  \draw[yshift=\cmdTKZ@ell@shift cm,dashed] (#4,0) arc(0:180:#4 and #5);
  \draw[yshift=\cmdTKZ@ell@shift cm ] (-#4,0) arc(180:360:#4 and #5); 
  \path[fill=\cmdTKZ@ell@color,opacity=0.5,shade](#2 cm,#3 cm) ellipse (#4 and #5);  
}

\def\tkzCone{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@cone}{\tkz@cone[]}} 
\def\tkz@cone[#1]#2#3#4{%
 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bb}{#2*#3}          
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\bb*\bb/#4}  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{#2*sqrt((1-\yy)/#4)} 
\fill[color=Maroon!10] (0,#4)--(-\xx,\yy)  arc(180:360:\xx cm and .5 cm); 
\ellipseThreeD[color=Maroon!30](0,0)(\xx cm,.5 cm)
\draw (0,#4)--(\xx,\yy);
\draw (0,#4)--(-\xx,\yy); 
}% 

\def\tkzCylinder{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@cylinder}{\tkz@cylinder[]}} 
\def\tkz@cylinder[#1]#2#3#4{% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bb}{#2*#3}          
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\bb*\bb/#4}  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{#2*sqrt((1-\yy)/#4)}
  \fill[color=Maroon!10] (-\xx cm,0)--(-\xx cm,#4 cm)  
         arc(180:360:\xx cm and .5 cm)--(\xx cm,0) 
         arc(360:180:\xx cm and .5 cm);   
\ellipseThreeD[color=Maroon!30](0,0)(\xx cm,.5 cm)
\begin{scope}[yshift=#4 cm]
  \draw[fill=\cmdTKZ@ell@color,opacity=0.5,shade](0,0) ellipse (\xx cm and .5 cm) ;  
\end{scope}
\draw (\xx cm,0)--(\xx cm,#4 cm);
\draw (-\xx cm,0)--(-\xx cm,#4 cm); 
}%  

\begin{document}    

 \tikz  \tkzCone{3}{0}{5};
  \hspace{1cm}
 \tikz   \tkzCylinder{3}{0}{5};

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try so far? Do you have any code to start with? Is the picture you show how you would the output to be like?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I'm learning to make 3d Tikz pictures (haven't done much, besides the examples in the posted link). Yes, the code to produce the shown picture would awesome!

Comment: It is always better if you provide some code of what you tried so far. It is easier to help you then. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Note that putting them together adds more hidden lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably just draw it like this (thanks to [this answer](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1781) for the hint about how to calculate the critical angle):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, line join=round, line cap=round]

% define tilt angle
\pgfmathsetmacro{\TiltAngle}{20}    

% CONE
% calculate critical angle where tangentials intersect ellipsis
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ConeHeight}{3.06} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ConeRadius}{1.4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CritAngle}{acos((\ConeRadius/2)/\ConeHeight)} 

% draw tangentials
\draw[thick, orange, fill=orange!10]
    ({180-\CritAngle}:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        -- ({-\ConeHeight},0) coordinate (A)
        -- ({180+\CritAngle}:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius});
% draw visible part of base
\draw[thick, orange, fill=orange!20] 
    (270:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) coordinate (B)
        arc[start angle=270, end angle=\TiltAngle, 
            x radius={\ConeRadius/2}, y radius={\ConeRadius}];
\coordinate (E) at (90:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius});

% HALF CYLINDER
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CylinderHeight}{2.2}  

% draw base
\draw[thick, orange, fill=orange!20]
    ([shift={(right:\CylinderHeight)}]\TiltAngle:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        arc[start angle={\TiltAngle}, end angle={-(180-\TiltAngle)}, 
            x radius={\ConeRadius/2}, y radius={\ConeRadius}];
% draw bottom part
\draw[thick, orange, fill=orange!10] 
    ({180+\TiltAngle}:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        arc[start angle={180+\TiltAngle}, end angle=270, 
            x radius={\ConeRadius/2}, y radius={\ConeRadius}]
        -- ++(\CylinderHeight,0) coordinate (C)
        arc[start angle=270, end angle={180+\TiltAngle}, 
            x radius={\ConeRadius/2}, y radius={\ConeRadius}];
% draw cut surface
\draw[thick, orange, fill=orange!10] 
    (\TiltAngle:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        -- ({180+\TiltAngle}:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        -- ++(\CylinderHeight,0)
        -- ([shift={(right:\CylinderHeight)}]\TiltAngle:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        -- cycle;

% draw hidden part of cone base
\draw[densely dashed, orange] 
    (270:{\ConeRadius/2} and {\ConeRadius}) 
        arc[start angle=-90, end angle=\TiltAngle, 
            x radius={\ConeRadius/2}, y radius={\ConeRadius}];

% AXIS
\draw[densely dashed, orange] ({-\ConeHeight-0.25},0) -- ({\CylinderHeight+0.5},0);

% ANNOTATIONS
\draw (A) -- ({-\ConeHeight},-2) coordinate (a);
\draw (B) -- (0,-2) coordinate (b);
\draw (C) -- (\CylinderHeight,-2) coordinate (c);
\draw (C) -- (C -| {\ConeHeight+0.5},0) coordinate (d);
\draw (E) -- (E -| {\ConeHeight+0.5},0) coordinate (e);

\draw[<->] ([yshift=5pt]a) -- ([yshift=5pt]b) node[midway, below] {30,6};
\draw[<->] ([yshift=5pt]b) -- ([yshift=5pt]c) node[midway, below] {22};
\draw[<->] ([xshift=-5pt]d) -- ([xshift=-5pt]e) node[midway, right] {28};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Jasper! (+1, just don't have enough rep to give it)

Answer (score 3):

My Asymptote code just uses the [extrude](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577773/140722) command. The first base `b1` is a circle that gives horizontal cone after extruding, while the second base `b2` is a half of circle that gives horizontal half-cylinder after extruding

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(2mm);
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,1,.6,center=true,zoom=.8);
pen p=yellow;
real r=14;
real y1=30.6,y2=22;
triple V1=(0,-y1,0),V2=(0,y2,0);
path3 b1=circle(O,r,normal=Y);
path3 b2=arc(O,(r,0,0),(-r,0,0),normal=Y)--cycle;
draw(extrude(b1,V1--cycle),p);
draw(extrude(b2,V2),p);
```